# Numpy matrix operations

Tags: python, matrix, numpy

I want to compute the following values for all `i` and `j`:

```
M_ki = Sum[A_ij - A_ik - A_kj + A_kk, 1 <= j <= n]
```

How can I do it using Numpy (Python) without an explicit loop?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a general strategy for solving this kind of problem.

First, write a small script, with the loop written explicitly in two different functions, and a test at the end making sure that the two functions are exactly the same:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import newaxis

def explicit(a):
    n = a.shape[0]
    m = np.zeros_like(a)
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                m[k,i] += a[i,j] - a[i,k] - a[k,j] + a[k,k]
    return m

def implicit(a):
    n = a.shape[0]
    m = np.zeros_like(a)
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(n):
                m[k,i] += a[i,j] - a[i,k] - a[k,j] + a[k,k]
    return m

a = np.random.randn(10,10)
assert np.allclose(explicit(a), implicit(a), atol=1e-10, rtol=0.)
```

Then, vectorize the function step by step by editing `implicit`, running the script at each step to make sure that they continue staying the same:

Step 1

```
def implicit(a):
    n = a.shape[0]
    m = np.zeros_like(a)
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            m[k,i] = (a[i,:] - a[k,:]).sum() - n*a[i,k] + n*a[k,k]
    return m
```

Step 2

```
def implicit(a):
    n = a.shape[0]
    m = np.zeros_like(a)
    m = - n*a.T + n*np.diag(a)[:,newaxis]
    for k in range(n):
        for i in range(n):
            m[k,i] += (a[i,:] - a[k,:]).sum()
    return m
```

Step 3

```
def implicit(a):
    n = a.shape[0]
    m = np.zeros_like(a)
    m = - n*a.T + n*np.diag(a)[:,newaxis]
    m += (a.T[newaxis,...] - a[...,newaxis]).sum(1)
    return m
```

Et voila'! No loops in the last one. To vectorize that kind of equations, [broadcasting](http://www.scipy.org/EricsBroadcastingDoc) is the way to go!

Warning: make sure that `explicit` is the equation that you wanted to vectorize. I wasn't sure if the terms that do not depend on `j` should also be summed over.

Comment: Really nice answer, and great general advice!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Great advice for the future :)